# How to get a specific string near a static text?

Tags: regex

I've a list of links that contains the id of a country, an example is this.

```
/national/italy/serie-a/20172018/regular-season/r42011/?ICID=PL_3N_01
```

essentially I need to get the number `42011` that is near the "r" character, unfortunately I'm not a regex expert so I need a bit help to achieve this target.

Comment: Please specify language in tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never told us what tool/language you are using, but the typical way you would use regex here would be to *capture* the `r42011` term in a capture group.

The following pattern should work:

```
.*/(r[0-9]+)/.*
```

The `r42011` term (or whatever variant might appear) will be available in the first capture group.  The coding/tool details again depend on what you are using, but hopefully this pattern sets you on the right track.

### Demo